# check for null when using sql data reader

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm reading data using sql command and sql reader like

```
using (var reader = command.ExecuteReader())
{
   if (reader.Read())
   {
         // how can I check is reader["Name"] != null?
        myObj.Name = (string)reader["Name"];
   }
}
```

Comment: `if (!reader.IsDBNull["Name"]) {`

Answer (score 1):

You can use IsDBNull

```
if(!reader.IsDBNull("Name")){
    myObj.Name = (string)reader["Name"];
}
```

Unless you can do as:

```
if (reader["Name"] != DBNull.Value)
{
   myObj.Name = (string)reader["Name"];
}
```

OR

```
myObj.Name  = (reader.IsDBNull("Name")? "": sqlreader.GetString(indexofName));
```